# USPS IntlRateV2 - country list

Tags: usps

I'm using USPS IntlRateV2 API to retrieve shipping rates for international customers.

The problem I'm facing is that USPS requires to fill in a country name (not the 2 characters code for it, but the full name) that causes me troubles getting rates for countries that have no straightforward name, for example: south Korea and there are many of such countries.

Does anyone can come up with a list of all USPS supported countries?

I've tried contacting the USPS but no reply given.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: dd you find an answer to this? I am facing  the same troubles, given 40 some countries are failing the shipping check

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice snippet to get the list off USPS website:
https://github.com/tajmorton/extract_usps_countries/blob/master/extract_countries.py

Credit goes to: taj morton